# How can I access MainActivity.java Class method on FragmentActivity.java Class.?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-spinner

I'm just facing problem when i m trying to call MainActivity method on my fragment activity. please let me know  how can i fix it.

here is the method code snippet inside - **MainActivity.java**

-> this code is just for retrieving name column from database so that I could load on my spinner which is in a ***FragmentActivity.java***.

```
 public List<String> getAllLedgerName(){
    List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
    //select All Query
    String Selectquery = "Select name from Ledger_info";
    SQLiteDatabase dbname = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursorname = dbname.rawQuery(Selectquery, null);

    if(cursorname.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            names.add(cursorname.getString(0));
        }while (cursorname.moveToNext());
    }
    return names;

}
```

-> here is the code of **FragmentActivity.java** class where i want to call above method to load retrieved data on spinner.

```
 private void loadSpinnerData() {

     ControllerActivites ca =  (ControllerActivites)getActivity(); 
    List<String> namelist = ca.getAllLedgerName();
    //create adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,namelist);
    //list view with drop down
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //attaching data adapter to spinner
    spin_Sales_Party.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Its not loading the data rather it crashes my app when I do perform this action.

Whatever I have written initializing and method calling code I think that's not correct please give me solution or if you think is there any error in rest of code then please let me know. thanks.

Comment: create instance of activity

Comment: simply instantiate is not the solution for fragment. I have already done that.

Comment: i have done like Activity act = MainActivity.getInstance(); and act you can access MainActivity method  or   MainActivity.getInstance().updateFragment();

Comment: create getInstance method in activity

Comment: nothing happened even there is no such call back method getInstance() of any activity class. how did you do this. I gone through another solution but its also not working ..                                                       Activity ca = getActivity();
        if(ca instanceof MainActivity)
        {
            ((MainActivity)ca).getAllLedgerName();
        }